# Variable has not have been initialized in Java

Tags: java, initialization, switch-statement, return

The following code fails to compile as the variable 'rt' has not been initialized.

I'm wanting the code to either initialize 'rt' in the switch-Statement, or not use 'rt' anymore when the default case is ran.

Here is the code I've written:

```
enum RequestType {leader, candidate};

private void processRequest(String input) {


        boolean inputOK = true;
        RequestType rt;

        String[] split = input.split(":");

        if (!input.contains(":")) {
             inputOK = false;
        }
        else {


            if (split.length != 3) {
                inputOK = false;
            }

            else {
                int port = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);

                if (!(port > 0 && port < 65537)) {
                    inputOK = false;

                }

                else {

                    switch (split[0]) {
                        case "Leader":
                            rt = RequestType.leader;
                            break;
                        case "Candidate":
                            rt = RequestType.candidate;
                            break;
                        default:
                            inputOK = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        if (!inputOK) {
            return;
        }

        String address = split[1].concat(split[2]);

        if (rt == RequestType.leader) {

            keepingLeader(address);
        }
```

Comment: You don't initialize `rt` in the default block, or many of the ifs. The compiler doesn't look at whether the read of `rt` is reachable with respect to the value of `inputOK`, it just looks at whether it is reachable at all.

Comment: yes but I am assigning false to requestOK which would then lead to rt not being used anymore. edit: okay that explains it. how can i handle this here as  I don´t really have a default value to assign to rt

Comment: Local variables don't have default values, so you can't use them (for instance while comparing) without explicitly initializing them first, even with `null`.

Comment: Or, instead of having a separate `inputOK` variable, use `rt == null` to indicate that the input isn't ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't initialize `rt` in the default block, or many of the ifs.

The compiler doesn't look at whether the read of `rt` is reachable with respect to the value of `inputOK`, it just looks at whether it is reachable at all.

The easiest thing to do is just to return immediately where you currently have `inputOK = false;`.

Alternatively, you can assign a default value to `rt`, for example `null`, when you declare it. The problem with that is it breaks the checking that the compiler is doing now - that you actually have assigned it in all circumstances, so you don't accidentally use the default value.

Instead, you can use the nullity of `rt` instead of having a separate boolean value:

- Where you currently assign `inputOK = false`, assign `rt = null` instead;
- Where you then check `!inputOK` and return if true, check `rt == null` instead.

Comment: Perfect Answer. I am going to use the check of `rt == null` because I want to do some add some things to do before returning which I then don´t have to code every time when now `inputOK == false` is assigned